# disabling why run mode for platform resources in chef

Tags: chef-infra

Extract from link
https://docs.chef.io/lwrp_custom_provider_ruby.html

`why-run mode is already enabled for platform resources. When platform resources are used as part of the action block in a lightweight provider, only the whyrun_supported? is required to allow the chef-client to run in why-run mode.`

Once I make whyrun_supported true, is it possible to disable it for specific resources (e.g. a resource cookbook_file that will always run but is not relevant to the policy and therefore should not be picked up as an action in case the cookbook is run in why-run mode)

Example:
`cookbook_file "setLastUpdateDate.ps1" do
          path "#{ENV['TMP']}\\setLastUpdateDate.ps1"
          action :create
        end`

`execute "Set the last update date of signatures" do
          cwd "#{ENV['TMP']}"
          command "powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -command \"& #{ENV['TMP']}\\setLastUpdateDate.ps1\" "
          action :run
        end`

`if some_value > other_value then
converge_by("This is the corrective action") do
  execute "RunSomething to modify signature update interval" do
              cwd "#{ENV['TMP']}"
              command "some_corrective_command"
            end
    end`

The policy in why run mode should respond only if the last execute block will be run or not(since it is the block that performs the corrective action and relevant). The first two blocks are more of a prerequisite steps in order that I can determine later whether the endpoint needs corrective action or not. Therefore I was hoping if there is a way wherein why run ignores the first two resource blocks

**Partial resolution**

Why_run does not detect commands run through shell_out.
e.g. In your provider, add

```
class Provider
class MseCheck < Chef::Provider
  include Chef::Mixin::ShellOut

def whyrun_supported?
    true
  end

  def action_fix

    command1 = "ipconfig ; hostname ; mkdir C:\\tempFolder "
    shell_out!("powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted -command \"#{command1}\"")
end
end
end
```

Even if the policy makes changes to the system through shell_out, why_run will not give the update of it.

Comment: Can you provide a better example? `cookbook_file` is a core resource and doesn't run every time - only when the destination file isn't there/up to date (depending on the action)

Comment: and why do you want to do that? Chef's build-in resources support why-run, so why-run is fine by default? Why-run is about simulating "what would happen if", if you instead try to "hide" things that will happen, you're abusing why-mode IMHO.

Comment: @Roland Depending on its output we'll automate whether to run the cookbook or not. Hence the need to hide. So I assume there isn't a way then ? (even if my intention seems to be abusive :) )

Comment: Chef's philosophy is to converge everything, everytime but prevent duplicate actions. If you need some kind of "workflow" you can use notifies/subscribe https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifications. The goal is, that chef not only makes changes once but also checks the status on each run (a kind of "self-healing" approach).

Comment: @Ivan you're still wrong, that's not the shell_out but the fact you did not embed it within a converge_by("message") block which makes it happen. Indeed an execute resource would have it's own converge_by wrapper and so won't execute. But any ruby code not embedded in a converge_by when why-run is true will be interpreted.